# Error CS1061 al utilizar AddRange

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de C#
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Dictionary<string, string> variables;
        Dictionary<string, string> InitialVariables = null;

        variables.Add("tmp", "");
        if (InitialVariables != null)
        {
          variables.AddRange<string, string>(InitialVariables);
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio me resalta [CS1061](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1061)) sobre `AddRange`.

Comment: de donde sale AddRange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede implementar `AddRange` en un `Dictionary` ya que al implementar un `AddRange` esto supone que los pares de un diccionario (clave, valor), se puedan duplicar.
Actualmente `AddRange` se puede implementar en `List`.

Comment: cual seria la solución sin usar addrange? un foreach añada cada valor de InitialVariables?

Comment: Es lo único que queda hacer.  Puedes leer esta respuesta donde dan una posible solución pero al final obtendrás una brecha no documentada en el framework: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050633/why-doesnt-dictionary-have-addrange